# How to invalidate NSTimer inside tablecell

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I am using following method to delete table cell but it doesn't invalidate timer which is running inside that cell.

```html
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

Comment: That is because tablecell are cached and reused, better not to but a `NSTimer` inside the cell.

Comment: I am changing image inside table cell every 1 second based and reading imagename from variable present inside table view controller. imagename gets changed every 1 second in tableview controller so I have to change image in tablecell for every 1 second. How should I do it?

Comment: Use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` and pass the Index Path of the cell that needs updating from the `UIViewController`

Comment: I want to change only imageview. e.g. If reload cell every 0.2 seconds doesn't it hamper the performance ?

Comment: Maybe, depends on what else is in the call. But since Cell are reused and cached you should not keep something like a timer in a cell. You might use KVO to check it the object bound to the cell has changed.

Comment: Do you have any example for KVO table cells.  I little struggled with KVO but couldn't remove observer. When I scroll my table cell and again visit the same cell it re-adds observer and tablecells got repeated..

Comment: Implemented with KVO and working. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do instead:

First, I would ensure each cell has a unique identifier of some sort.
Then, I would create an NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary as a property of your UIViewController that stores each cell's corresponding NSTimer.
Next, if a reference to the NSTimer from a table view cell is absolutely necessary, I can create a weak reference to the NSTimer in the dictionary.
Then, when I go to delete the table view cell, I can also invalidate the timer by looking it up in the NSArray/NSDictionary and then deleting it.